# Get the difference for a column value by all its previous rows data

Tags: database, postgresql

Please consider these two tables:

1. Vault

   - id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
   - name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
2. Transaction

   - id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
   - transaction_type VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL -- Choice between "credit" or "debit"
   - amount NUMERIC(15,6) NOT NULL
   - vault_id BIGINT REFERENCES Vault (id)

When getting Transaction row/s, I would like to get an extra column for the remaining vault balance after the transaction is done.

Example of Transaction:

```
id      transaction_type        amount      vault_id        vault_balance
1       credit                  100         1               100 // since there was no prev transaction for this vault
5       credit                  400         1               500
12      debit                   200         1               300
20      credit                  100         1               400
```

I can add a column to hold the vault balance and use that for the next transaction. But suppose the user deletes a row, for example row id 5 which has credit amount of 400 is deleted. Then its following transactions vault balance should change accordingly. So for row 12 the vault balance would be -100, and row id 20's vault balance would be 0.

```
id      transaction_type        amount      vault_id        vault_balance
1       credit                  100         1               100 // since there was no prev transaction for this vault
12      debit                   200         1               -100
20      credit                  100         1               0
```

The way I see it I have two ways:

- Add a column to store the vault balance in a transaction, and if there is a change, all of its following transaction's vault balance should be updated accordingly.
- Maybe there's a way to get the difference of credit and debit between all of its previous and the current transaction amount.

But I am hoping there is a much better way? Could you please help me what would be most efficient way to handle such situation?

**Update**

[Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2e3312565b94473184dc14e4d5daefff) to the Table fiddle.

Comment: You can add a trigger on delete and update the next with `vault = vault - old.amount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way, at least IMHO. Do not change your table definition, instead create a `view` on transactions which has the running balance and that column is derived in the view.

```
    create view transactions_with_bal as 
    select id 
         , transaction_type
         , amount
         , vault_id
         , sum(amount * case when transaction_type = 'credit' then 1 else -1 end )
               over (partition by vault_id order by id) balance 
       from transactions;
```

Now you do not need any additional processing for DML (delete, insert, update) against the table; no trigger, no additional code, nothing. Also you avoid race conditions when multiple users issue DML against it at the same time. It even handles the case where the column `vault_id` changes.

Comment: Thank you! I am just learning about window functions. Could you also help me how can I get the vault balance for just one row, i.e. by ID?

Comment: Just add a where clause when selecting from the view.  So `Select * from  transactions_with_bal where id = <desirded id>;`